# Joomla module not working

Tags: plugins, joomla, module

I made a module that display how many days ago a article was published
it looks like this.

```
{source}

<?php
    $jinput = JFactory::getDocument()->input;
    $option = $jinput->get('option');
    $view = $jinput->get('view');
    if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& $jinput->get("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    $date = new JDate($article->get("publish_up"));

    $currentTime = new JDate('now');

    $interval = $date->diff($currentTime);

    if($interval->d == 0) {
            echo 'dzisiaj' . "<br>";
        }
        else if( $interval->d == 1) {
            echo 'wczoraj' . "<br>";
        }
        else if( $interval->d > 1) {
            echo $interval->format('%a dni temu') . "<br>";
        }


}

?>

{/source}
```

And it works on my local joomla but when use it on custom template it doesnt work. I'm using Joomla 3.4.8.

Comment: Do you get an error message. "it doesnt work" is not very detailed, and makes it difficult to help you, without installing the same Joomla version and testing with standard and custom template to see the difference

Comment: I doesn't display any error. I tried installing some random custom template and it worked. Maybe this template i'm working with is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're trying to access the input values using `Document Factory` that's wrong you have to use

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

Document Factory is  used for other purpose like adding , styles or Js to the pages etc. read more about [input here](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput).

Hope it make sense.